# How to debug a C DLL (Plugin)?

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, plugins, teamspeak

I am writing my first C DLL and I am curious how to debug or test my code? As the plugin itself can not run alone. Is it possible to debug the loaded DLL?
I am using Visual Studio and the Plugin is for Teamspeak 3, if that matters :)

Thanks in adcance.

Comment: In VS you can use the "Attach to Process..." debug menu to connect to the program that loads the dll. I'm not sure if all versions of VS support this.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp okay sounds good. At the moment I am creating a DLL file and copy it into the plugin folder. How does VS know which DLL to atach to?

Comment: Oh okay I can directly Attach to my Teamspeak process.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp this works really well. You saved me a lot of time! :D